# side-by-side in revision history does not render stacksnippet

Tags: bug, revision-history

While looking at the revisions for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/27892657/revisions) I noticed that no changes were shown for revision 2. Those changes are shown in markdown-mode, but not in inline-mode or side-by-side mode. I would consider this to be a bug.

I suspect that transformation from a few code blocks to a stacksnippet might have something to do with this. Still, besides this change, numerous newlines were removed.

[image: Screenshot of revision history with empty second revision]

Comment: Interestingly, this works in the side-by-side markdown view.